# conda env export --from-history does not track channels

Tags: python, conda, environment

I've installed several packages from different channels (`-c rdkit rdkit` and `-c pytorch pytorch`), and I'm only seeing `defaults` under channels in the output of `conda env export --from-history`. Is there a flag I'm missing?

I do see a `--ignore-channels` option, is it that `--from-history` turns on `--ignore-channels` by default somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "explicit spec" doesn't track temporary changes to channels like that. For example, if you installed

```
conda install -n my_env -c rdkit rdkit
```

it only treats the `rdkit` as the explicit spec. Technically, the above doesn't actually specify that `rdkit` must come from the **rdkit** channel. Instead, a more accurate interpretation is:

> *With the channel **rdkit** prioritized, ensure that **my_env** has some version of `rdkit` installed.*

I think what you were hoping for (auto-adding of channels to envs) could be a useful behavior, but it is likely something to raise on the GitHub Issues and propose an expected behavior.

### Including channel info in explicit specs

In the meantime, one can include channels explicitly in specs, e.g.,

```
conda install -n my_env rdkit::rdkit
```

which should result in literally `rdkit::rdkit` being included in the explicit spec. That is, "install `rdkit` from the **rdkit** channel".

### Adding channels to an env

To explicitly add a channel to an env, one needs to activate the env and the use the `conda config --env`. For example,

```
conda activate my_env
conda config --env --add channels rdkit
```

Note, there are other options like `--prepend` and `--append` if one needs to be more precise about the priorities.

Comment: Explicit include does the trick for me. That seems to be the more narrow way of specifying requirements in the first place, if as you say the -c argument does not actually guarantee that the package comes from that channel.