# `ResolvePackageNotFound` when Creating Conda Environment created with `--history`

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

When creating a new Conda environment by running the command

```
conda env create -f environment.yml --prefix foo
```

and having the `environment.yml` file (created using `conda env export --from-history > environment.yml`)

```
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
  - emoji
  - pandas
```

I'm getting the error

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - emoji
```

Also tried

```
CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1 conda env create -f environment.yml
```

but its giving the same error.

I think the `emoji` package was previously installed using `conda install -c conda-forge emoji`

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda env export --from-history does not track channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015144/conda-env-export-from-history-does-not-track-channels)

Comment: @FlyingTeller Is there a command to find out all the channels used in an environment? This way, the list of channels can be manually added to `environment.yml`

Comment: Not aware of one. You could parse the result of `conda list --explicit`

Comment: @FlyingTeller the `--explicit` output isn't the cleanest for parsing channels. Something like `conda list | awk '{if ($1 !~ /^#/) {print $4}}' | sort -u` might be better. Note that *blank* entries correspond to **defaults** channel.